# Xcode 12.0 not showing variable when debugging

Tags: xcode

I have projects that I have created with earlier releases of Xcode. I was forced to upgrade to Xcode 12.0.
When I run my old projects, not tried all of them, I am not getting any variable declared outside of the current routine, the variables within the current routine do not show any value. I have created a new project and the same thing applies. I have checked old reports and all my optimization settings are none, and I have debug for my Build configuration along with many of the other suggestions on earlier versions of Xcode with the same problem. So there's probably something very simple that I need to do but I can't find it. Hope somebody has the solution.

Answer (score 2):

for me what did the change is removing facebookSDK from swift packages and return to use pods.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try going to warnings and pressing update to recommended settings?

Edit: The warnings are found in the tab that looks like an exclamation mark.[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find warning please.

Comment: Tried "defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode" from Terminal and it did NOT do the trick.

Comment: @DavidRogers I have added it as an image above.

Comment: No that did not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Open Menu

1. Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Test
2. Tab [Info -> LLDB Init File]
3. Paste the following link

   ```
    $(SRCROOT)/.lldbinit
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using Xcode 12.5.1, and eventually solved it by changing my default interactive shell to zsh, then closing and reopening Xcode.

To change the default interactive shell to zsh, use this command in a terminal (command line) window:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

I had already ensured that both Objective C and Swift were being compiled with no optimisation in debug mode, and that I was running a debug build of my app.

Before I made the change I couldn't see any variables, and no lldb commands worked. The change fixed both those problems.